# SonarQube not able to insert into MySql database

Tags: mysql, exception, jdbc, sonarqube

I have downloaded **[SonarQube 6.7 (LTS)](https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/)** and I have followed the instructions in [this](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+the+Server) page.
But it seems there is a problem related to the database. I am using **MySQL 5.7** for the database and I have created a schema named **sonar** in it and also put the proper database settings in the **sonar.properties** file. On the database side, I have added the user for SonarQube and also given it admin privileges. But whenever I start the web server, it gets stopped and when I check the web logs in the file **web.log** I saw there is an exception. It seems it cannot insert an entry into the table **schema_migrations** which seems to be caused by:

`Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The table does not comply with the requirements by an external plugin.`

I checked the database and I saw that the tables were created successfully by SonarQube. Where is the problem arising from? and Why? Could this be a primary key issue?

Below is the complete log:

```
2017.12.15 17:03:35 INFO  web[][o.s.p.ProcessEntryPoint] Starting web
2017.12.15 17:03:35 INFO  web[][o.a.t.u.n.NioSelectorPool] Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
2017.12.15 17:03:36 INFO  web[][o.e.p.PluginsService] no modules loaded
2017.12.15 17:03:36 INFO  web[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.index.reindex.ReindexPlugin]
2017.12.15 17:03:36 INFO  web[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.join.ParentJoinPlugin]
2017.12.15 17:03:36 INFO  web[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.percolator.PercolatorPlugin]
2017.12.15 17:03:36 INFO  web[][o.e.p.PluginsService] loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
2017.12.15 17:03:38 INFO  web[][o.s.s.e.EsClientProvider] Connected to local Elasticsearch: [127.0.0.1:9001]
2017.12.15 17:03:38 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.LogServerVersion] SonarQube Server / 6.7.0.33306 / 5d031d9d2ac3f69b4b9bc600d50563b1886c7d8b
2017.12.15 17:03:38 INFO  web[][o.sonar.db.Database] Create JDBC data source for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3310/sonar?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&rewriteBatchedStatements=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance&useSSL=false
2017.12.15 17:03:39 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerFileSystemImpl] SonarQube home: D:\Programs\sonarqube-6.7
2017.12.15 17:03:39 INFO  web[][o.s.s.u.SystemPasscodeImpl] System authentication by passcode is disabled
2017.12.15 17:03:39 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.h.MigrationHistoryTableImpl] Creating table schema_migrations
2017.12.15 17:03:40 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin Flex / 2.3 / 79167f762219bea1fd181ff5ef6ca4b34abd1675
2017.12.15 17:03:40 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarC# / 6.5.0.3766 / 6011a1e9fb002edb044ae3092d92bcfb7d9d8a2d
2017.12.15 17:03:40 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarJS / 3.2.0.5506 / 86da09565f891121df248835665f5d8ed98772b6
2017.12.15 17:03:40 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarJava / 4.15.0.12310 / 572454b93016ec73a53fe0e07b2ffdc356d21ba9
2017.12.15 17:03:40 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarPHP / 2.11.0.2485 / 741861a29e5f9a26c6c99c06268facb6c4f4a882
2017.12.15 17:03:40 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarPython / 1.8.0.1496 / 3fe3bc4d0273a5721ea2fb368dc45b1bb82fede3
2017.12.15 17:03:40 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarQube :: Plugins :: SCM :: Git / 1.3.0.869 / 4da53e3f9e55f4f2e5796625cb0c5768ed152079
2017.12.15 17:03:40 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarQube :: Plugins :: SCM :: SVN / 1.6.0.860 / 2111fdbd1dddda4ad6d4ed6486fd0b18c1010d3b
2017.12.15 17:03:40 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarTS / 1.1.0.1079 / 042c9e65239a47d92d305f9767f730b3cc1e5ed3
2017.12.15 17:03:40 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.ServerPluginRepository] Deploy plugin SonarXML / 1.4.3.1027 / 39588245cecf538bb27be4e496ff303b0143d20b
2017.12.15 17:03:46 INFO  web[][o.s.s.p.d.m.AutoDbMigration] Automatically perform DB migration on fresh install
2017.12.15 17:03:46 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] Executing DB migrations...
2017.12.15 17:03:46 INFO  web[][DbMigrations] #1 'Create initial schema'...
2017.12.15 17:07:17 ERROR web[][DbMigrations] #1 'Create initial schema': failure | time=211172ms
2017.12.15 17:07:17 ERROR web[][DbMigrations] Executed DB migrations: failure | time=211172ms
2017.12.15 17:07:17 ERROR web[][o.s.s.p.Platform] Web server startup failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to insert row with value 1 in table schema_migrations
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.history.MigrationHistoryImpl.done(MigrationHistoryImpl.java:88)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.execute(MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.java:76)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.execute(MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.java:67)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEachOrdered(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.step.MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.execute(MigrationStepsExecutorImpl.java:52)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.engine.MigrationEngineImpl.execute(MigrationEngineImpl.java:52)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.AutoDbMigration.start(AutoDbMigration.java:65)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.invokeMethod(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:110)
    at org.picocontainer.lifecycle.ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.start(ReflectionLifecycleStrategy.java:89)
    at org.picocontainer.injectors.AbstractInjectionFactory$LifecycleAdapter.start(AbstractInjectionFactory.java:84)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.AbstractBehavior.start(AbstractBehavior.java:169)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored$RealComponentLifecycle.start(Stored.java:132)
    at org.picocontainer.behaviors.Stored.start(Stored.java:110)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.potentiallyStartAdapter(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1016)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.startAdapters(DefaultPicoContainer.java:1009)
    at org.picocontainer.DefaultPicoContainer.start(DefaultPicoContainer.java:767)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:134)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.platformlevel.PlatformLevel.start(PlatformLevel.java:90)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.start(Platform.java:211)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.startSafeModeContainer(Platform.java:203)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:104)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.Platform.doStart(Platform.java:95)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.web.PlatformServletContextListener.contextInitialized(PlatformServletContextListener.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4745)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5207)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The table does not comply with the requirements by an external plugin.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2490)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1858)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1197)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.execute(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:172)
    at org.sonar.server.platform.db.migration.history.MigrationHistoryImpl.done(MigrationHistoryImpl.java:83)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Is there a primary key in `schema_migrations`?

Comment: Did you check all MySQL requirements on the [SonarQube requirements](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements) page?

Comment: @Mick No. I did not explicitly create any or add a primary key to the table.

Comment: @Jeroen Yes. I've checked it thoroughly.

Comment: Okay, I think the first google hit for "The table does not comply with the requirements by an external plugin" was about a table missing the primary key. Can you add a primary key there?

Comment: I just re-installed MySQL with the same configuration, that is, I just removed MySQL and installed it the same way I did last time and now it works. I have no idea why or how.

Answer (score 1):

This exception comes from the MySQL driver. You seems to have installed a MySQL plugin that forbid to create the table `schema_migrations`.

Maybe you have installed "Group Replication" plugin and hit this exception like https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=83165

Answer (score 0):

This is not the solution, but I re-installed MySQL server with the same configuration and users (along with privileges) and now its working, for reasons I cannot understand.

I have not been able to determine what the issue was, and I don't know how to replicate the problem also because the same action produced different results.